# windbg help missing kernel32 function

Tags: windbg, kernel32

I am trying to follow this tutorial here https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2201303 specifically the part where it mentions x kernel32!*writeprocessmemory*

I am unable to find the method kernel32!WriteProcessMemory =  even though documentation mentions it but i can find
 kernel32!_imp__WriteProcessMemory and  kernel32!WriteProcessMemoryStub. I am new to windbg and trying to follow the tutorial so i am not sure if this method has been deprecated and if so, what is it's substitute and how do we achieve similar functionality.

Thanks

Comment: 0:000> .foreach (place { x /1 kernel32!*wr*pr*me*} ) { dps place l1 } from windows 7 onwards many functions have been moved into different dlls and API-SET is used which resolves all these old functions to new dlls you are probably using an xp era tut / doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exported `WriteProcessMemory` function in fact points to the `kernel32!WriteProcessMemoryStub` stub which itself jumps onto the `kernel32!__imp_WriteProcessMemory` which redirects to the `kernelbase` DLL which is the "real" location for this function.

Let's check with a link dump:

```
C:>link /dump /exports c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll | findstr /I WriteProcess
       1579  62A 00036C50 WriteProcessMemory
```

0x36C50 is the RVA where the function "WriteProcessMemory" resides in kernel32 (as given by the export table). Now in windbg:

```
0:007> ln kernel32 + 0x36c50
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

(00007ff9`4a6e6c50)   KERNEL32!WriteProcessMemoryStub   |  (00007ff9`4a6e6c60)   KERNEL32!ZombifyActCtxStub
```

We have an exact match which is in fact the `KERNEL32!WriteProcessMemoryStub` function. If we look at it:

```
0:007> u KERNEL32!WriteProcessMemoryStub
KERNEL32!WriteProcessMemoryStub:
00007ff9`4a6e6c50 48ff2599150400  jmp     qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_WriteProcessMemory (00007ff9`4a7281f0)]
00007ff9`4a6e6c57 cc              int     3
```

We can see it's just a jump to `KERNEL32!_imp_WriteProcessMemory` (located somewhere in the `.idata` section of kernel32).

Now if we look at what is contained at this location, we have a pointer:

```
0:007> dp KERNEL32!_imp_WriteProcessMemory L1
00007ff9`4a7281f0  00007ff9`496f0ca0
```

If we ask windbg what is this pointer:

```
0:007> ln 00007ff9`496f0ca0
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

(00007ff9`496f0ca0)   KERNELBASE!WriteProcessMemory   |  (00007ff9`496f0dc4)   KERNELBASE!OpenWow64CrossProcessWorkConnection
Exact matches:
    KERNELBASE!WriteProcessMemory (void)
```

We can see that in fact the "real" location for the `WriteProcessMemory` is in fact in `kernelbase.dll`.

---

note: you can actually do the last two commands in one with `dps`:

```
0:007> dps KERNEL32!_imp_WriteProcessMemory L1
00007ff9`4a7281f0  00007ff9`496f0ca0 KERNELBASE!WriteProcessMemory
```

---

Windbg command used:

- [`ln (List Nearest Symbols)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ln--list-nearest-symbols-): given an address, find the nearest symbol.
- [`u (unassemble)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/u--unassemble-): used to disassemble a function
- [`dp (display memory)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/d--da--db--dc--dd--dd--df--dp--dq--du--dw--dw--dyb--dyd--display-memor): display memory (**p**ointer sized).

  - [`dps(Display Words and Symbols)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dds--dps--dqs--display-words-and-symbols-): as `dp` but with symbolic information.

Comment: Thank you so much! by any chance do you recommend some resources for windbg learnings, there seems to be an overwhelming number but none that set you into practice!

Comment: One more question when i am checking the stack i notice in some examples it has format of CHILD EBP Return address and then information. While in mine it shows CHILD SP return address and information, is there a reason some stacks with k command show up differently?

Comment: @Mohamed341 1) The only "tutorial" I can think of, on the top of my head, is in the [Practical Reverse Engineering Reversing](https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Reverse-Engineering-Reversing-Obfuscation/dp/1118787315) book (disclaimer: it was written by friends of mine) There's a dedicated chapter about practicing with windbg.  2) It depends on the windbg 'flavor' you are using: the x86 version shows "Child EBP" while the x64 version shows "Child SP" (even when debugging x86 code).